# How to avoid typical errors in building an investment portfolio in the R language

Tags: r, portfolio, r-portfolioanalytics

I just started studying portfolio analysis in R language, I came across an article that explains the basic principles by [example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/portfolio-optimization-using-r-and-plotly/). But there were problems with this code. The code contains the following errors: 
1) the Portfolio cannot be optimized due to constraint full_investment; 
2) a problem with writing the vector;
3) the Sharpe ratio is not calculated;
4) a problem with plotting.
So who is interested in this, let's start parsing the code

```
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(zoo)
library(plotly)
library(foreach)
library(DEoptim)
library(iterators)
library(fGarch)
library(Rglpk)
library(quadprog)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(ROI.plugin.quadprog)
library(ROI.plugin.symphony)
library(pso)
library(GenSA)
library(corpcor)
library(testthat)
library(nloptr)
library(MASS)
library(robustbase)
# Get data
getSymbols(c("MSFT", "SBUX", "IBM", "AAPL", "^GSPC", "AMZN"))
# Assign to dataframe
# Get adjusted prices
prices.data <- merge.zoo(MSFT[,6], SBUX[,6], IBM[,6], AAPL[,6], GSPC[,6], AMZN[,6])
# Calculate returns
returns.data <- CalculateReturns(prices.data)
returns.data <- na.omit(returns.data)
# Set names
colnames(returns.data) <- c("MSFT", "SBUX", "IBM", "AAPL", "^GSPC", "AMZN")
# Save mean return vector and sample covariance matrix
meanReturns <- colMeans(returns.data)
covMat <- cov(returns.data)
# Start with the names of the assets
port <- portfolio.spec(assets = c("MSFT", "SBUX", "IBM", "AAPL", "^GSPC", "AMZN"))
# Box
port <- add.constraint(port, type = "box", min = 0.05, max = 0.8)
# Leverage
port <- add.constraint(portfolio = port, type = "full_investment")
# Generate random portfolios
rportfolios <- random_portfolios(port, permutations = 500000, rp_method = "sample")
```

This part of the code passes without errors, but then...

```
# Get minimum variance portfolio
minvar.port <- add.objective(port, type = "risk", name = "var")
# Optimize
minvar.opt <- optimize.portfolio(returns.data, minvar.port, optimize_method = "random", rp = rportfolios)
# Generate maximum return portfolio
maxret.port <- add.objective(port, type = "return", name = "mean")
# Optimize
maxret.opt <- optimize.portfolio(returns.data, maxret.port, optimize_method = "random", rp = rportfolios)
```

When optimizing for objectives, the following error is displayed in each of the points:

```
Leverage constraint min_sum and max_sum are restrictive, consider relaxing. e.g. 'full_investment' constraint should be min_sum=0.99 and max_sum=1.01
```

I have no idea why this error occurs, but for some reason the replacement of the full_investment facet with Leverage or another, the error disappears. Then comes the second error:

```
# Generate vector of returns
minret <- 0.06/100
maxret <- maxret.opt$weights %*% meanReturns
vec <- seq(minret, maxret, length.out = 100)
```

An error is thrown when receiving a vec element:

```
Warning message:
In seq_len(length.out - 2L) * by :
  Recycling array of length 1 in vector-array arithmetic is deprecated.
  Use c() or as.vector() instead.
```

Perhaps this error can be ignored, since the data was still written

```
eff.frontier <- data.frame(Risk = rep(NA, length(vec)),
                           Return = rep(NA, length(vec)), 
                           SharpeRatio = rep(NA, length(vec)))

frontier.weights <- mat.or.vec(nr = length(vec), nc = ncol(returns.data))
colnames(frontier.weights) <- colnames(returns.data)

for(i in 1:length(vec)){
  eff.port <- add.constraint(port, type = "return", name = "mean", return_target = vec[i])
  eff.port <- add.objective(eff.port, type = "risk", name = "var")
  eff.port <- add.objective(eff.port, type = "weight_concentration", name = "HHI",conc_aversion = 0.001)
  eff.port <- optimize.portfolio(returns.data, eff.port, optimize_method = "ROI")
  eff.frontier$Risk[i] <- sqrt(t(eff.port$weights) %*% covMat %*% eff.port$weights)
  eff.frontier$Return[i] <- eff.port$weights %*% meanReturns
  eff.frontier$Sharperatio[i] <- eff.port$Return[i] / eff.port$Risk[i]
  frontier.weights[i,] = eff.port$weights
  print(paste(round(i/length(vec) * 100, 0), "% done..."))
}
```

After these manipulations, an effective portfolio is created that meets the conditions, but an effective frontier cannot be built (in the table named eff.frontier does not fill the Sharp ratio column)

Next, I also wanted to build plot based on the available data, but there were errors again:

```
feasible.sd <- apply(rportfolios, 1, function(x){
  return(sqrt(matrix(x, nrow = 1) %*% covMat %*% matrix(x, ncol = 1)))
})

feasible.means <- apply(rportfolios, 1, function(x){
  return(x %*% meanReturns)
})

feasible.sr <- feasible.means / feasible.sd

p <- plot_ly(x = feasible.sd, y = feasible.means, color = feasible.sr, 
        mode = "markers", type = "scattergl", showlegend = F,

        marker = list(size = 3, opacity = 0.5, 
                      colorbar = list(title = "Sharpe Ratio"))) %>% 

  add_trace(data = eff.frontier, x = Risk, y = Return, mode = "markers", 
            type = "scattergl", showlegend = F, 
            marker = list(color = "#F7C873", size = 5)) %>% 

  layout(title = "Random Portfolios with Plotly",
         yaxis = list(title = "Mean Returns", tickformat = ".2%"),
         xaxis = list(title = "Standard Deviation", tickformat = ".2%"),
         plot_bgcolor = "#434343",
         paper_bgcolor = "#F8F8F8",
         annotations = list(
           list(x = 0.4, y = 0.75, 
                ax = -30, ay = -30, 
                text = "Efficient frontier", 
                font = list(color = "#F6E7C1", size = 15),
                arrowcolor = "white")
         ))
```

Although there is a Risk column in the table eff.frontier, the function still does not find it:

```
Error in add_trace(., data = eff.frontier, x = Risk, y = Return, mode = "markers",  : 
  object 'Risk' not found
```

I just wanted to explain these problems, because my programming skills are not enough to understand the essence of these problems.

Original code: https://www.r-bloggers.com/portfolio-optimization-using-r-and-plotly/

Comment: Hi @EugeneRB, I can see you are using quantmod, can you also show the libraries you are using? And maybe start with 1 problem first? I am sure the rest can be tackled

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf, I add all libraries which I use

Comment: Try to focus on one problem